# Question - c++ terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::out_of_range' what(): basic_string::substr:?

Tags: c++

I'm new to coding and trying to create a program to encrypt/decrypt based on a map of 26 characters. The encryption part of the code works, but whenever I try to decrypt, I get the error

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::out_of_range'
  what():  basic_string::at: __n (which is 122) >= this->size() (which is 5).
```

What should I do?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

string encrypt(string word, string map = "zyxwvutsrqponmlkjihgfedcba") {
    string output = "";
    for(int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++) {
        int pos = word.at(i) - 'a';
        output += map.at(pos);
    }
    return output;
}

string decrypt(string word, string map = "zyxwvutsrqponmlkjihgfedcba") {
    string output = "";
    for(int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++) {
        int pos = map.at(i);
        output += word.at(pos) + 'a';
    }
    return output;
}

int main() {
    string method, word, map;
    cout << "What is the method (encryption or decryption)? ";
    cin >> method;
    if(method.compare("encryption") != 0 && method.compare("decryption") != 0) {
        cout << "Error: invalid method choice.\n";
        return 0;
    }
    cout << "What is the translation map (type 'default' to use default): ";
    cin >> map;
    if(map.compare("default") && method.length() != 26) {
        cout << "Error: invalid translation map size.\n";
        return 0;
    }
    cout << "What is the single word to translate: ";
    cin >> word;
    if(method.compare("encryption") == 0) {
        for(int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++)
            if(!isalpha(word.at(i)) || !islower(word.at(i))) {
                cout << "Error: encryption cannot be performed.\n";
                return 0;
            }
        if(map.compare("default") == 0)
            cout << "Encrypted word: " << encrypt(word) << endl;
        else
            cout << "Encrypted word: " << encrypt(word, map) << endl;
    }
    if(method.compare("decryption") == 0) {
        if(map.compare("default") == 0)
            map = "zyxwvutsrqponmlkjihgfedcba";
        for(int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++)
            if(map.find(word.at(i)) == string::npos) {
                cout << "Error: decryption cannot be performed." << endl;
                return 0;
            }
        if(map.compare("default") == 0)
            cout << "Decrypted word: " << decrypt(word) << endl;
        else
            cout << "Decrypted word: " << decrypt(word, map) << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh, please, please, indent. But the `what()` text pretty much tells you exactly the problem. You're trying to access character 122 in a 5-character string.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you're misunderstanding the meaning of string::at.

Consider the lines:

```
int pos = map.at(i);
output += word.at(pos) + 'a';
```

`at` simply gives you back the ASCII value of the character at position `i` in the string. Supposing `i` is zero, this is 'z' which has an ASCII value of 122.

You then try to look up the character at position 122 in `word`, `word` does not have that many characters. I'm not sure exactly what you're trying to do, but it's not that.

Comment: Thanks Jasper! I appreciate the input.